# Avaialble plugins are not showing in SonarQube server

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube5.1

On SonarServer, `Settings->Update Center -> Available Plugins` i can see error `Not connected to update center. Please check your internet connection and logs.`. The machine has internet connections and i've setup HostName and Port also. Because of above problem i placed plugins in Plugins folder. Any sugesstions please?

[image]

Comment: As stated by the error message: Did you check logs ?

Comment: Before Adding Host address - org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Fail to download: http://update.sonarsource.org/update-center.properties (no proxy)

After Adding Host address - org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Fail to download: http://update.sonarsource.org/update-center.properties (HTTP proxy: 256.256.256.256:12345)

In sonar.properties 

# HTTP proxy (default none)
http.proxyHost=256.256.256.256
http.proxyPort=12345

Answer (score 1):

Download the required plugin jar file from internet.
paste it to (installation directory)sonar-3.7.4\extensions\plugins folder.
And then run startsonar.bat from the bin folder.
It will appear in dashboard.